# vi creating a swap files before create a new file

Tags: linux, vim, nfs

This is a strange problem. the swap file get created for the new files. so, my directory is empty there is no file exist and then when I `vi test.txt` I get the swap file message. It looks like the `vi` create .swp files as crash dump and show me that restore file message.

```
    nfs setting:
    netapp-3240:/vol/vol0/test /testing nfs  rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr     0 0

    [user@rh-test]cat /etc/redhat-release
    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.9 (Tikanga)

    [user@rh-test]ls -la
    total 8
    drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Nov  8 15:35 .
    drwx------ 9 root root 4096 Nov  8 13:59 ..
    /testing 
    
    [user@rh-test]vi test.txt


    E325: ATTENTION
    Found a swap file by the name ".test.txt.swp"
              owned by: rahmed   dated: Fri Nov  8 15:30:06 2013
             [cannot be read]
    While opening file "test.txt"
                 dated: Fri Nov  8 15:29:59 2013

    (1) Another program may be editing the same file.
        If this is the case, be careful not to end up with two
        different instances of the same file when making changes.
        Quit, or continue with caution.

    (2) An edit session for this file crashed.
        If this is the case, use ":recover" or "vim -r test.txt"
        to recover the changes (see ":help recovery").
        If you did this already, delete the swap file ".test.txt.swp"
        to avoid this message.

    Swap file ".test.txt.swp" already exists!
    [O]pen Read-Only, (E)dit anyway, (R)ecover, (D)elete it, (Q)uit, (A)bort:

    [user@rh-test]ls -la
    total 8
    drwx------ 2 root   root          4096 Nov  8 15:39 .
    drwx------ 9 root   root          4096 Nov  8 13:59 ..
    -rwx------ 1 user   sysadmins    0 Nov  8 15:39 .test.txt.swo
    -rwx------ 1 user   sysadmins    0 Nov  8 15:39 .test.txt.swp
```

of course if I create a file by echo then no swap file.

```
    [user@rh-test]echo "this is test file" > test.txt

    /testing
    [user@rh-test]ls -la
    total 8
    drwx------ 2 root   root          4096 Nov  8 15:29 .
    drwx------ 9 root   root          4096 Nov  8 13:59 ..
    -rwx------ 1 user   sysadmins   18 Nov  8 15:29 test.txt
```

The output of `:set dir` is `directory=.,~/tmp,/var/tmp,/tmp`

Please note that this is only happening on this nfs mount `/test`. the other local and nfs mounts on same system not having this issue.

mount options:

`netapp-3240:/vol/vol0/test on /testing type nfs (rw,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr,addr=10.200.23.22)`

**After changing to nfsvers=2 it is starting working**

nfsvers=2 or nfsvers=3 — Specifies which version of the NFS protocol to use. This is useful for hosts that run multiple NFS servers. If no version is specified, NFS uses the highest supported version by the kernel and mount command. This option is not supported with NFSv4 and should not be used.

`netapp-3240-2:/vol/vol1/testing on /test type nfs (rw,rsize=16384,wsize=16384,intr,nfsvers=2,addr=10.200.23.22)`

**

### Resolved:

#### This issue was related to NetApp option not set correctly. In order to resolve this we had to set this option on NetApp `options cifs.ntfs_ignore_unix_security_ops on` on NetApp.**

Comment: `:set dir` in vim says?

Comment: updated the vi output of `:set dir`

Comment: @SLm yes, I can but please note that this issue is only happening on this `/test` nfs mount other nfs mount and local disk are not having this issue.

Comment: Sounds like your issue: http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/network-internet/414143-really-strange-nfs-issues.html

Comment: Yes I saw your updates, so now realize it's an NFS issue w/ vim.

Comment: Can you show the mount options for the NFS share? You can get them via the `mount` command.

Comment: @slm updated mount options that shows by `mount` command

Comment: For comparison purposes, I use these options: `rw,intr,tcp,nfsvers=3,rsize=16384,wsize=16384,addr=192.168.1.1`. I'd be tempted to take out the `timeo`.

Comment: Ok changed to your suggested settings but still same thing: netapp-3240:/vol/vol1/test on /testing type nfs (rw,rsize=16384,wsize=16384,intr,tcp,nfsvers=3,addr=10.200.23.22)

Comment: Can you try tracing this? `strace vim somefile 2>&1 | tee trace.txt`. I'd like to see this output, it will likely show us where it's getting hung up. Make sure to ping me `@slm` otherwise I might not see your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Email thread

I found this thread from 2008, seems dated, but it sounds exactly like your issue. It would appear to be something with NetApp specifically. I noted that in your output the server was named `netapp-3240` which I assumed was a NetApp appliance.

The thread is titled: [strange behaviour, Linux and NFS on NTFS qtree](http://network-appliance-toasters.10978.n7.nabble.com/strange-behaviour-Linux-and-NFS-on-NTFS-qtree-td5372.html). Specifically there is mention of the same symptoms you're experiencing.

#### Synopsis of problem

*excerpt*

> I'm seeing some strange behaviour with a FAS3040 filer I have on 
>   evaluation at the moment. I have an NTFS-style qtree exported by NFS and 
>   CIFS. Debian Linux clients see odd behaviour relating to open() and 
>   stat64() system calls. This strace output from "vim" captures it in a 
>   nutshell:
>
> ```
>    uname({sys="Linux", node="acheron", ...}) = 0 
>     stat64("ffff", 0xbfb4d030) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) 
>     stat64("ffff", 0xbfb4d0b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) 
>     access("ffff", W_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) 
>     open("ffff", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) 
>     readlink("ffff", 0xbfb4c7cc, 1023) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) 
>     open(".ffff.swp", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) 
>     open(".ffff.swp", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied) 
>     stat64(".ffff.swp", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
> ```
>
> Note that the open(O_RDWR...) call fails with EACCES; but the following 
>   stat64() call succeeds. The file ffff.swp was created on disk despite 
>   the reported failure of the open() call.
>
> This behaviour is seen using "vim" to edit files, and causes an error 
>   message about the swap file being present (due to the swap file being 
>   created even though the open() return value implies it was not).
>
> Trying the same "vim" command on a Tru64 NFS client, correct behaviour 
>   is seen: the open(O_RDWR...) succeeds and a filehandle is returned.

#### nfsver=2

There was this suggestion which fixed the issue. You could try it for no other reason than to confirm that you're experiencing the same issue that this thread is addressing.

*excerpt*

> But after your email I tried vers=2 and the problem goes away (with both 
>   TCP and UDP) which is interesting indeed. Although with the crazy size 
>   files and filesystems around here, NFSv3 is very desirable.

Doing something like this on your exports:

```
rw,intr,tcp,nfsvers=2,rsize=16384,wsize=16384,addr=192.168.1.1
```

#### cifs.ntfs_ignore_... option

There was one additional thing to try in the thread:

> Setting the option cifs.ntfs_ignore_unix_security_ops to on on the filer might work.

#### What else?

Beyond these things there were several other things to try that I was not able to confirm, given I don't have access to a NetApp filer on which to try. There were some URLs to the NetApp website too which you could explore, but I did not have access to confirm any of these things either.

At any rate, I would highly suggest you go through this thread, since it seems to be the leading candidate for your odd `vim` saying it has a .swp file when it in fact does not.

Comment: The `nfsvers=2` works. this is also strange since I am mounting it from NetApp and other mounts works fine except this one. I need to talk to NetApp folks to figure out what exactly they did differently on this export. Thanks you so much for ding so hard on this issue for me.

Comment: @Salton - yeah, no problem. If you find out a resolution, can you please come back and close the loop here? I for one would be curious to know what the ultimate issue is/was.

Comment: finally, discovered that this issue is related to NetApp option needs to 
set to 'options cifs.ntfs_ignore_unix_security_ops on'. I will also update this in my questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good thread, thank you all.

I figure I should add on to it since we're seeing this exact same issue... on a non-NetApp storage provider.

We're running Oracle Enterprise Linux 7 with UEK 5 and every time we try to create a file on an EMC data domain, we get the error about a swp file pre-existing for vi for files we are creating on the fly.

Turns out, this appears to be a bug in the UEK 5 kernel. We switched the server from UEK 5 to UEK 4 and things work as expected. We'll likely open a ticket with Oracle about the issue.